# How to use :value for list values in hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate

I know that I can write so:

```
Query query = session.createSQLQuery(
"select s.stock_code from stock s where s.stock_code = :stockCode")
.setParameter("stockCode", "7277");
List result = query.list();
```

How I must do if I use list values

```
select count(*) from skill where skill.id in (1,2,4)
```

I want replace hardcode values.

Comment: Why won't you use criteria's ,any restrictions ??

Comment: very nice tutorial for that: http://www.javaranch.com/journal/200510/Journal200510.jsp#a2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Query interface have `setParameterList(List<any>)` function to set the value in `IN` Clause in HQL. But in HQL `IN` Clause have a limit to set the element. If the limit is exceed, memory overflow exception occur.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe:

```
   Query query = session.createSQLQuery("select count(*) from skill where skill.id in :ids")
    .setParameter("ids", Arrays.asList(1,2,4));
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this?

```
Query query = session.createSQLQuery(
"select s.stock_code from stock s where s.stock_code in (:stockCodes)")
.setParameter("stockCodes", "1,2,4");
```

Does it work for you?